Has Android Studio recently changed its default AVD storage location?
I recently fired up Android Studio after a hiatus of several weeks, and it couldn't find any of my existing AVDs. I dug around a bit, and discovered that while it had previously stored and looked for them in $HOME/.android/avd (as per the official documentation), it is now storing and looking for them in $HOME/.config/.android/avd. (I've seen this using several different builds of Android Studio.) The OS is Debian Linux. I have no ANDROID* variables set. Is there some other setting that controls this that may have somehow changed, or has Google just changed the IDE defaults (and neglected to update the documentation)?
Edited slightly for clarity.

ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME and ANDROID_AVD_HOME haven't changed.

Okay, so why is AS looking for AVDs in the wrong directory unless I manually set ANDROID_AVD_HOME?
